# Python code is skipping to else

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, skip

Hi so this is my code an for some reason after the last for loop the code just skips straight to the else statement and prints it about 4 times and then goes to the if statement and prints the solution. Please can someone help with this.

```
while True:
   d = {}
   with open("keyword_database.txt") as f:
       for line in f:
          (key,val) = line.split(":")
          d[str(key)] = val
   try:
      userinput=input(str("What is the problem with your phone?\nEnter here in lower:"))
      print()
   except:
      print ("Invalid Input")
   for word in userinput.split(): 
           if word in d:
              print(d[word])
              print()
           else:
              print("Please Re-Phrase your problem and Try Again")
              print()
```

And this is what it prints once I run the code.

> What is the problem with your phone? Enter here in lower: my phone is
>   broken
>
> Please Re-Phrase your problem and Try Again
>
> Please Re-Phrase your problem and Try Again
>
> Please Re-Phrase your problem and Try Again
>
> Problem = Broken Solution = Take your phone to the repair shop and get
>   it fixed from there however do keep in mind if someone else opens your
>   phone apart from apple then the warrenty will be VOID (NOT ACTIVE).

Comment: That's because `'my'`, `'phone'` and `'is'` are not in `d`. So for *those three words* your `else` branch is used instead. You need to rethink how you test for a word match.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for word in userinput.split(): 
    result = ""
    if word in d:
        result += d[word] + "\n"

if (len(result) == 0):
    result += "Please Re-Phrase your problem and Try Again\n"
print (result)
```